# Python 3 | Beautiful Soup For Loop, Variable not assigned

Tags: regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm in the process of learning Python, and I decided to train a bit of my programming by trying to make a program that could research text in a site called "Library of Babel" (https://libraryofbabel.info/)

I'm using BeautifulSoup to get the actual text out of the HTML code and I'm then using Regular Expressions to search for what I'm looking for, in this case I was testing it with just the leter "a".
But for some reason the code gives a error and says the variable I'm searching the "a" on, is not assigned.

Code:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://libraryofbabel.info/browse.cgi"
pages,data=[],[]

r = requests.get(url)
r = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(r,"html.parser")

for text in soup.findAll("li",{"onclick":"gethexfromlist(this.innerHTML); enterhex();"}):
    page = text.string
    pages.append(page)

for eachRoom in pages:
    url = "https://libraryofbabel.info/browse.cgi?" + eachRoom
    for eachWall in range(1,5):
        url = url + "-w" + str(eachWall)
        for eachShelf in range(1,6):
            url = url + "s-" + str(eachShelf)
            for eachVolume in range(1,33):
                if len(str(eachVolume)) == 1:
                    url = url + "-v0" + str(eachVolume)
                else:
                    url = url + "-v" + str(eachVolume)
                    for eachPage in range(1,411):
                        url = url + ":" + str(eachPage)
                        r = requests.get(url)
                        r = r.text
                        soup = BeautifulSoup(r,"html.parser")
                        for text in soup.findAll("div",{"class":"bookrealign"}):
                            rdata = text.string
                        if data == []:
                            data = re.findall(r"a",rdata)
                        else:
                            break
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...", line 37, in <module>
    data = re.findall(r"a",rdata)
NameError: name 'rdata' is not defined
```

**Thanks in advance for any help given :)**

Comment: Are you sure that the result of `soup.findAll("div",{"class":"bookrealign"})` is never empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if is outside the loop and `soup.findAll("div",{"class":"bookrealign"})` finds nothing so *rdata* never  gets defined.